# User can't access Organisation in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I am new at Liferay, please help me this problem.
**Firstly**, I create a new Organisation named : Sample Organisation.
**Then**, I create a new Role named : Sample Creator.
**Then**, I create a new User and **assign** Sample Organisation, Sample Creator to this user.
**Finally**, I sign in this new user.

**But** I can't find Sample Organisation as the bottom image.
Thank all.

http://www.liferay.com/c/message_boards/get_message_attachment?messageId=22771000&attachment=liferay+training.jpg

Comment: What version of liferay are you using? If it's 6.x, you won't see organizations in that way... what you are looking for is a web site

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay 6.1 Organizations *can* have a site attached to them, but this is not mandatory. There's an item called "Organization Site" with a checkbox "Create Site" that you'll have to check in order to have a site.

Plus, in order to be able to navigate to such a site, it will have to have pages.

Both are frequent reasons for people missing access to a site (or organization).

In Liferay 6.0 the first step is not necessary: An organization *is* a site in that version, but you'll still have to have pages.

Comment: Thank Olaf Kock, I have got it. I really appreciate your helping.
Hope to see you again